# Windows 8 Charms (disable swipe)

Tags: windows-8

I have a Dell XPS13 and just upgraded to Windows 8 - I am constantly triggering the Charms bar just using the trackpad as I have for months. It has a Cypress trackpad but nowhere in the settings does it mention Windows 8 gestures.

I've read [How can I disable the Windows 8 charms bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/399029/how-can-i-disable-the-windows-8-charms-bar) and [Modify or disable Windows 8 swipe gestures on touchpad / laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/494705/modify-or-disable-windows-8-swipe-gestures-on-touchpad-laptop) - neither of these help. I would just like to turn off the trackpad gesture.

Comment: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-touchpad-gestures-in-windows-8/ modifies the registry to disable gestures on Synaptics touchpads; I wonder if there's a Cypress equivalent fix... sadly, Windows 8 doesn't support disabling them in the OS.

Comment: Beware that disabling the charms means you won't have access to useful shortcuts and features like: contextual search from Windows 8 apps, you won't be able to access the Shut Down/Restart button (unless you create specific shortcuts on the Start screen or the Desktop), the Settings charm which allows you to configure Windows 8 and Windows 8 apps.

Comment: To understand what these charms do, why they are important and why you should not disable them, read this guide: http://www.7tutorials.com/introducing-windows-8-what-are-charms

Comment: Corporate Geek or Microsoft rep? .... Anyway - if you read my question again - you'll see I don't want to disable the Charm bar - even though I've not used it once since installing Win8 - I just want to disable the trackpad from activating it. It's *so* infuriating!

Comment: From what I've read, ensuring that the latest BIOS (A07 for the L321X specifically mentions Win8 support) and trackpad drivers are installed will enable you to customise settings: [L321X](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/Product/xps-13-l321x), [L322X](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/Product/xps-13-l321x-mlk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dell have updated the Cypress drivers on [their website](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/Product/xps-13-l321x) - The newest version has separate checkboxes for up, left + right swipe gestures

Answer (score 1):

[This forum post answer](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/20992-touchpad-edge-swipes-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html#post251427) resolved my problem. Simply put, there should be an option called "Edge Swipes" in your touchpad configuration software.

For Synaptic touchpads:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to open setting search and type "mouse"
2. Select "Mouse" from the center column
3. Select the last tab "Device settings" and press "Settings"
4. Deselect "Enable Edge Swipes"

If you do not have this option, [grab the latest version of the Synaptics drivers from their website](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers).

For UltraNav (Lenovo laptops):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to open setting search and type "mouse"
2. Select "Mouse" from the center column
3. Select the last tab "UltraNav" and press "Settings" in the "TouchPad" box
4. Expand "Application gestures" and select "Edge swipes"
5. Deselect "Enable Edge Swipes"

You may need to reboot your machine after applying these changes.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Windows 8 swipe gestures are temporarily disabled on the touchpad if you hold down the shift key while moving the cursor. (I use a Lenovo Ideapad).

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable gestures in Windows 8 for the Cypress trackpad.

Control Panel / Modify mouse parameters / Cypress Trackpad tab. Then, uncheck the gestures you want to get rid off and enjoy your ultra portable, finally!